# Make API call for every item in a collection and return final results in list

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to make an API call (getAccounts) that returns a list, then make a second list that by making a call(get for details of every object in that list (instead of just the first in the block below). How do I do that and then notify the observer when that series of calls is complete?

```
  viewModelScope.launch {
            gateway.getAccounts(

            ).fold(
                onSuccess = { v ->
                    // fetch account details for first credit account in list
                    gateway.getCreditAccountDetails(v.first().accountId, v.first().accountIdType).fold(
                        onSuccess = { v -> addAccountToList(v)}
                    )
                }
            )
        }
```

Coroutines functions:

```
   suspend fun getAccounts(): Result<List<LOCAccountInfo>> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            AccountServicing.getCreditAccounts(creditAuthClient)
        }
    }

   
    suspend fun getCreditAccountDetails(accountId: AccountId, accountIdType: AccountIdType): Result<LOCAccount> {
        return getCreditAccountDetails(accountId, accountIdType, creditAuthClient)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What about applying `map` to the list, and using `async` function along with the `awaitAll` extension?

The `async` function will run the subtasks parallelly with concurrent coroutines. Finally, the `awaitAll` extension will wait till all coroutines are complete.

```
viewModelScope.launch {
            gateway.getAccounts().map { account ->
                println("Account -> $account")

                async {
                    gateway.getCreditAccountDetails(
                        account.first().accountId,
                        account.first().accountIdType
                    ).let { creditDetails ->
                        println("Credit Details -> $creditDetails")
                    }
                }
            }.awaitAll()

            // Notify the View/Observer
            println("All API execution is complete")
        }
```

Notes: Instead of using the hardcoded `Dispatchers.IO` in your **gateway**, pass the dispatcher from the **ViewModel** or **DI** module. This is helpful if you plan to unit test and swap the **IO** dispatcher with the **Main** dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `fold` you could use the function `map` to iterate over the original list and create a new list with the details. Then, you could just assign the result to the `LiveData`/`StateFlow` or whatever reactive object you are using there.